# Laravel: Could not insert data but don't catch any error

Tags: laravel, exception, insert

I try to run a cronjob to insert about 60000 rows into DB:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
            DB::table('pharmacies')->delete();
            foreach(array_chunk($data, 50) as $piece) {
                Pharmacy::insert($piece);
            }
            DB::commit();
            \Log::debug("Save successfully");
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::debug($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The cronjob is working normally. I test for a few first times, it saves successfully. But then, It suddenly can't save and from this time the data can't save without any error.
I don't know why the data can't save but it doesn't catch exceptions to log the error message?
Any idea or suggestion for this case. Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel Framework 7.30.4

Answer (score 0):

What is your CORN-JOB configuration? check /var/log/syslog for logs

Comment: Actually, I can check log on laravel.log on local. But it works normally on my local. 
And before insert data to DB, i implement another function in this job. And it's ok. So I'm sure that the cronjob is running.